# xml to swagger 2.0 spec conversion using golang

Tags: json, go, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am having trouble converting xml (WSDL) to swagger 2.0 specs in golang. i found a library on github that converts xml to normal json but i need to convert to swagger 2.0 json. suggest me libraries if any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What protocol are the WSDL bindings?  Are they SOAP or HTTP bindings?

Comment: @DarrelMiller http bindings

Comment: @DarrelMiller or else suggest me an example code of swagger 2.0 implementation using golang. all i want is the output has to be swagger 2.0 format

Comment: I'm not aware of any Go based tooling that will output OpenAPI/..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at these libraries: https://github.com/go-openapi.
I use them and they allow you to do pretty much everything you need.

You can use them to build the swagger 2.0 spec dynamically. But of course, you will need to write your custom code to parse your XML, convert it to swagger structures and after all, you will be able to write your dynamically created spec to the file in `json` or `yaml` format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using API transformer (https://apimatic.io) It is providing APU for conversion between all different API specs. Hope this helps.